# Call function from service worker on angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm developing a web application with Angular and I'm having a problem.

When my page is open I play an mp3 bell sound when push notifications are received by firebase cloud messaging.

I'm using a service worker to display notification when my browser is in another tab or in the background.

I would like the browser to play this sound when I get push notifications with my page in the background.

Is it possible to call the function that plays this bell sound through the service worker? or is there any other way to play it when i get the notification?

I used this example to create the service worker:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Thanks